# Xcode 7: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' vs 'NSUInteger'

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, xcode7

I just updated my Xcode to version 7.0 (7A220) and, unfortunately, I got several problems. Let me list those:

1. Now the images.xcassets provides support **only** for 1x, 2x, 3x. The Retina 4 2x box still exists for existing images but you cannot add new sets with Retina support. How can I handle that ?
2. My app **doesn't work anymore** for iPhone 4* and 5*. Images are disappeared: I can see only text (actually only launchscreen image works). I guessed that I might have had problem with iPhone 5* (No longer support for Retina 4) but I'm surprised about iPhone 4* (I used to create a -480 version of each image and put inside the 2x box). Here the same question: how can I handle that ?
3. I got several warnings: the first one was about "Update to recommended project settings" (Done but nothing changed).

The second is during runtime:

```
../ViewController.m:41:1: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

The third also during runtime:

```
(null): Directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

Can someone help me ? I'm using Xcode 7.0 (7A220) with SpriteKit for develop my app.

Comment: Too many questions rolled into one. This should be three questions; there's no useful way to answer this as posed. Info in (2) is too vague: "doesn't work anymore" is meaningless.

Comment: same issue for number (1), image assets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I solved those problems:

1) Apple seems doesn't support anymore Retina 4. This means that iPhone 4*, iPhone 5* and iPhone 6 need to be placed inside the @2x box. Surely it's trickier to handle fullscreen images, therefore you have to handle all programmatically.

2) I fixed this issue by setting all of the images to "**Universal**" instead of specific device (iPhone 4S and 5. Don't know why but iPhone 6 worked even with specific device). Anyways, bug or not I've notified Apple.

3a) The return type of the method `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` has changed, so if you get a warning such as `../ViewController.m:41:1: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')` you need to replace the return type.

```
// Before upgrading
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    ...
}

// After upgrading
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    ...
}
```

(Thanks to **Rainer Schwarze**)

3b) It seems the upgrade created issues in custom framework contexts (correct me if I'm wrong), this can be solved by **removing** the references from Build Settings.

[image: Items to remove]

Hope this could be helpful!

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the answer, I was stuck sith some of these problems and this was really helpful. But I'm not sure about how do you managed the second point. How do you set Images to Universal? Can you explain it a little more detailedly? Sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Try This for interface orientation warning:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000  
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#else  
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#endif  
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for sharing :)

Comment: Should be accepted answer as it allows backwards compile compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

I can give a hint for this warning:

> Conflicting return type in implementation of
>   'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka
>   'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned
>   int')

You need to replace the return type `NSUInteger` with `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` for the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. The return type has changed from iOS8 to iOS9.:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Eventually I ended up using this before the implementation part of the `.m` file where the type is used:

```
// Make compilable on iOS8:
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
#define UIInterfaceOrientationMask NSUInteger
#endif
```

This keeps the conditionals in one location and the snippet can easily be removed once iOS8 support is dropped.