# Warning on "(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations" method only on one class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing the following warning only in the new view controller subclass of UIViewController which I have created,

```
Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 
'nsuinteger' (ask 'unsigned long') vs 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' 
(ask 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask')
```

But, I have used the same method previously in one of the subclass of UIViewController but the warning is not shown in that view controller ?

Any reason why it happens ?

**Note*** I have just switched to XCode 8.1 and created the new class in it.

For reference code used

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```

Added reference code image as asked in comment:
[image]

Comment: Show us the method.

Comment: @NSNoob : I have added the screenshot of definition of that method in both the classes.

Comment: Don't add screenshots, nobody is going to steal your code if thats what you are afraid of. Add code!

Comment: @NSNoob : :-) I am not afraid of posting code, I just thought to show you the difference I face.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' vs 'NSUInteger'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671436/xcode-7-conflicting-return-type-in-implementation-of-supportedinterfaceorienta)

Comment: @NSNoob : I will check with the above question and close my question if it solves my need, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make similar method's return types in both .h and .m file .

Comment: Nice, now the warning got disappeared, But why should I add a function name in .h file ? I haven't declared the method in .h file before in old ViewController where I have used ? May I know the reason ?

Comment: did you use .pch file in your project ?

Comment: Yes I do have .pch file

Comment: so check your all .h file in your project and return type .